# ksql: create table and filter today's data based on timestamp

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am quite new to KSQL and just wonder how to extract today's data for aggregation? say I have the stream of count data with schema below:

```
Field     | Type
-----------------------------
 ROWTIME   | BIGINT
 ROWKEY    | VARCHAR(STRING)
 TS        | BIGINT
 COUNT     | BIGINT
```

How to create a table which would output the snapshot of todays sum of `COUNT` where `TS` is the UNIX timestamp using KSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TIMESTAMPTOSTRING` udf to change the `TS` value to your desired date format and then perform the sum. Here is one way to do this:

`CREATE STREAM mystream1 AS SELECT TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(TS, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS TS, COUNT_VAL FROM mystream;`

```
SELECT TS, sum(COUNT_VAL) FROM mystream1 GROUP BY TS;
```

You may want to rename `COUNT` column in your stream since it is function name in KSQL. You can also add WINDOW if you want to perform this over window.

Comment: now I have used the following command: `ksql> CREATE TABLE ATT_TS as SELECT TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(TS, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), SUM(counts) FROM counts_raw GROUP BY TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(TS, 'yyyy-MM-dd');`
but when I perform `ksql> select * from ATT_TS;


Exception in thread "ksql_query_1-bc21f435-0a92-4bdc-8a2c-d11ba4b899e8-StreamThread-40" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: I found that I have to create an intermediate stream to take out the date first, because `GROUP BY` seems cannot accept `TIMESTAMPTOSTRING` function yet...

Comment: Good point. Can you also create a github issue for this at https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql

Comment: Updated the answer :)